# Gathering IRC data at a set interval using python (socket module)

Tags: python, sockets, irc

I'm trying to gather data from my own Twitch IRC channel at certain time intervals. Using the python socket module, there are the two options to set for receiving data, "setblocking" and "settimeout".

I considered both, but they don't help when my goal is to just collect ALL data at, say, 30 seconds intervals. At the 30th second, I want to produce output and send it to the channel.

**settimeout(10)**:
It gives an error if it didn't fill the recv buffer in 10 seconds rather than return what it collected until that point. I was using try/except on its error:

```
socket.timeout: timed out
```

but that still does not give me the data.

**setblocking(0)**:
I also tried to put it to non-blocking mode but that results in:

```
socket.error: [Errno 11] Resource temporarily unavailable
```

Furthermore, I reckon that blocking it also is not the option since I just want what is returned in 30 seconds.

*So how can I gather all the data at 30 second intervals, ready to be processed?*'

MWE (fill in the variables to your settings):

```
import socket

irc = socket.socket()
irc.settimeout(10)

irc.connect((server, 6667)) 

#sends variables for connection to twitch chat 
irc.send('PASS ' + password + '\r\n')
irc.send('USER ' + nick + ' 0 * :' + bot_owner + '\r\n')
irc.send('NICK ' + nick + '\r\n')
irc.send('JOIN ' + channel + '\r\n')

irc.recv(1024)
```

Comment: To be sure you do in fact get all the data, best to have a thread looping continuously reading data from `recv` into a synchronized queue to ensure no data is lost from the socket. then in another thread you can have it read and process all the data from the queue in a loop with a 30 second sleep.

Comment: @MikeRixWolfe Sounds like a good idea. How to continuously read though while being able to read from it?

Comment: Perhaps make a generator out of the function getting data from the socket to put it in to the queue, and thread it to do both concurrently (not truly concurrent, but for this purpose it doesn't matter)

Comment: @MikeRixWolfe I think the main problem is that the receiving will be variable? What if I don't capture anything within 30 seconds? What if the receiver captures at 5 seconds, I still need the remaining 25 seconds even though that might just be collected AFTER the moment I analyze at the 30th second... I don't understand how time does not seem important, but buffer size apparently is important in managing IRC input.

Comment: You are mistaking processing with reading. read continuously into the queue where it just sits until the other loop that executes every 30 seconds processes that data. if it doesn't capture anything, nothing happens; that's what `if` statements are for. With IRC bots you must read continuously, but read it into something and then process it whenever you feel like. My irc bot does this, you can see it here https://github.com/MikeRixWolfe/Gary

Comment: Ironically I was looking at that (your) bot earlier today. This made me not use the bot: `data = self.recv_from_socket(4096)`. Doesn't it hang in that particular thread until the buffer is filled? So even though it does not hang the main thread, data is not immediately available since in order for it to send the collected data somewhere it first has to finish collecting the buffer?

Comment: That *thread* hangs and waits, but its not the main thread, the rest of the bot functions normally in other threads, yes. The reality of an IRC server and bot is you will *not* have continuous chatter constantly 24/7, that thread will wait on new data if theres no data present, and the loop processing the data can check if the queue isnt empty before processing, if its empty, wait another 30 seconds

Comment: Thanks a lot so far for answering. To add more context: I will use the chat for voting. I (the bot) will say something like "you have 30 seconds to vote", after which I count the votes in the chat and want to produce some output on the spot. How do you ensure that everything between "0-30 seconds" will be used? It seems that if `recv`, did not fill the buffer I won't have any output available even though people did in fact reply?

Comment: So for that specific need, we first need to define what needs to happen as a bot functions. The recv from socket is how the bot's core functions, this is different from the function of a plugin. The core doesn't need to be touched to accomplish this task, nor should it. What i'd do is make a plugin that (after you issue the command) records the start time, waits 30 seconds, records the end time, then quieries the logs for messages in that time frame, discerning relevant lines from chatter, and using them. The log function writing to the database in a spererate thread as the other is waiting.

Comment: Most IRC bots (like Gary) function essentially the same at the core level (depending on library like twisted, etc) but the core for all of them usually reads continuously, then handle things like you want to do with the plugins. One for logging all data forever, another to start the voting event and completing it and then doing the work with the data the logs have accumulated while it was waiting.

Comment: @MikeRixWolfe I indeed considered reading a file if that would solve the issue, but: there is no way to write lines in real time, right? Wouldn't that create the issue that `recv` will write at unpredictable times (when the buffer is full)? Some possible issues: at -1 seconds it finishes to buffer, followed by writing many messages occuring between 0-30 seconds at 31th second to a file. Or incomplete data, it writes at the 15th second (so there's only 15 seconds of data).

Comment: @MikeRixWolfe I guess that last comment most likely answered all my further questions.

Comment: Thanks Mike (and Gary)!